# strange MySQL join query results with aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, database, join, indexing, aggregate-functions

i wrote the following **join** query to get a report using **aggregate** functions

```
SELECT users.id, SUM(orders.totalCost) AS bought, COUNT(comment.id) AS commentsCount, COUNT(topics.id) AS topicsCount, COUNT(users_login.id) AS loginCount, COUNT(users_download.id) AS downloadsCount 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN orders ON users.id=orders.userID AND orders.payStatus=1 
LEFT JOIN comment ON users.id=comment.userID 
LEFT JOIN topics ON users.id=topics.userID 
LEFT JOIN users_login ON users.id=users_login.userID 
LEFT JOIN users_download ON users.id=users_download.userID 
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY bought DESC
```

but i don't know why i get the following output?

the result of aggregate functions are multiplied with each other!!!

i don't know why?

for example for the last row i expected the following result

```
821    |    48000    |    63    |    0    |    10    |    10
```

[image]

the result of executing EXPLAIN query are shown below

[image]

Comment: Show your expected result set and also provide proper ddls with some sample data @[*Sql Fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid see the expected result in my update. the result of  columns are multiplied except id column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason for that type of result would be you are using a left joins with your users table and the result set may contains the duplicate rows for each user so you are getting count  more than the expected one for this you can use `DISTINCT` in count to count only the unique associations per user and for sum of `totalCost` you can use a subselect to have a sum for each user without having repeated values for orders of user

```
SELECT 
  u.id,
  COALESCE(o.bought,0) bought
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) AS commentsCount, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) AS topicsCount, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT ul.id) AS loginCount,
  COUNT(DISTINCT ud.id) AS downloadsCount 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
           userID,
           SUM(totalCost) bought 
           FROM orders 
           WHERE payStatus=1 
           GROUP BY userID) o
ON u.id=o.userID
LEFT JOIN `comment` c ON u.id=c.userID 
LEFT JOIN topics t ON u.id=t.userID 
LEFT JOIN users_login ul ON u.id=ul.userID 
LEFT JOIN users_download ud ON u.id=ud.userID 
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY bought DESC
```

Comment: thank you very much, it's worked ;) if you explain more why the result contains the duplicate rows? (by simple words), i really appreciate that.

Comment: @MohammadMasoudian lets take an example if user 1 has 3 comments then with left join there will be 3 row per user and then another left join with topics  table and user have 5 topics the these 3 rows will be joined with 5 rows and resultant as 15 rows per user with duplicated rows for this purpose i have calculated sum in sub select and count with distinct,Hope this makes sense :)